# How to avoid writing an import for every single file in dart/flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am making a flutter application and I created a file/class for each custom widget I am using. Then, I imported all of these files into the main screen but I don't like how it looks. Especially because if I want to add another widget or delete the one I would need to fiddle with the imports.

Is there something like C# namespaces where I can just make one import for all files in folder/namespace?

I already tried using library/part with success but then in https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/create-library-packages says that I should avoid using part/part of. So, are we expected to import each and every file?

Instead of having:

```
import 'package:custom_widgets/custom_multiplechoice.dart';
import 'package:custom_widgets/custom_singlechoice.dart';
import 'package:custom_widgets/custom_time.dart';
import 'package:custom_widgets/custom_yesnochoice.dart';
import 'package:custom_widgets/custom_date.dart';
```

I would like to have:

```
import 'package:custom_widgets';
```

Comment: so use `export ...` from the link you posted

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes there is, you can use `export` to achieve what you want.

You can place all your widgets in a folder, for example `libs/src/` and then create file `custom_widgets.dart` in `libs/` and use `export` like this inside `custom_widgets.dart`:

```
export 'src/custom_multiplechoice.dart';
export 'src/custom_singlechoice.dart';
export 'src/custom_time.dart';
export 'src/custom_widgets/src/custom_yesnochoice.dart';
export 'src/custom_date.dart';
```

Once you `import` `custom_widgets.dart`, all those widgets will be available to you.

Check this out, its all explained here: [Dart: Organizing a library package](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#organizing-a-library-package)

Update:

In Dart there are no `namespaces` like in most other languages.
Dart uses `libraries` for encapsulation, data hiding.
Only way to import a class into your code is to use import in the beginning of your file, which should also be a library.

I have an issue with this too. Imagine a situation where you want to import library dynamically. Let's say you would like to implement `MVC pattern` in your application, if you are doing this on the server, you would have a `Router class` that would analyze URL and decide what `Controller class` to instantiate and what `Method` from that Controller to invoke. Now every URL would trigger different Controller, and you don't know it in advance, its up to your Router to detect a Class to instantiate. What you need to do in this situation is import every Controller that could get instantiated at the beginning of your file. And I have issues with that. What if your application gets big and you have to import lets say 20 Controller classes, just so Router / Dispatcher can invoke one of them, and in reality you will invoke only one Controller, as there is only Controller per URL.

Don't have issues with manual loading of Libraries, if they are going to be used, but for situation like described above, Dart fails as there is no "auto loading" of classes like in for example PHP, where you can use auto loaders that use namespaces to find out about location of your class and instantiate a class in the middle of the code dynamically.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. So I will always have to list the files no matter what? Is there something I could put inside each file to group them into 'custom_widgets' (like namespace declaring in c#)?  Ideally I would not like to fiddle with an extra file when adding new widgets.

Comment: Unfortunately at this moment in time, it looks like we have to import every class we want to use. There is no way to use namespaces the way you described and I too see it as a problem. I was looking for a way to import all libraries in given folder, but its not possible. Its an issue for me because what if you have the need to import library dynamically in the middle of the code. If you didn't import that library at the start of your library, you can't just import and instantiate your class later down the road. There is "deferred loading" in Dart, but again each library must be imported.

Comment: But how to disable visibility of all files not listed in main_package_file_with_exports.dart?

Comment: @Matija If I create a file to export all my custom widgets, then in one screen, I only use a couple of the custom widgets, would the unused ones still be exported? Will it have any side effects on the performance or memory side?

Answer (score 9):

There is this extension for VSCode which can help to create this.

[Dart Barrel File Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=miquelddg.dart-barrel-file-generator)