# How to import all Dart files from a Directory?

Tags: flutter, file, dictionary, dart

I am new to dart so please bear with me if this is really bad question. I am developing an app using flutter, and I have one question. I have many screens in my app, like About the App, Homepage, Upcoming Events, etc. I have kept all these screens in a folder in lib/screens directory. And to import them in main.dart for routes I have to import each and every file, like

```
import "screens/homepage.dart";
import "screens/aboutTheApp.dart";
import "screens/upcomingEvents.dart";
```

Is there a simpler way to do it? Is there a way to import the "screens" directory at once?

I have tried to import the complete folder and tried making it a package, but it isn't helping.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579092/how-to-avoid-writing-an-import-for-every-single-file-in-dart-flutter

Answer (score 38):

You can create a file in the `screens` directory and call it `all.dart` or whatever you like. In this file, you will simply export all of the *Dart files* in that folder:

```dart
export 'homepage.dart';
export 'aboutTheApp.dart';
export 'upcomingEvents.dart';
```

Now, whenever you want to use any file from that folder, you can just import `all.dart` or what you called it:

```dart
import 'screens/all.dart`;

...
```

*Other than that*, there is no possibility to import a **directory**.

Comment: It doesnt change anything. This just replace all the imports by exports.

Comment: @RémiRousselet if you have more than one file that needs all those widgets, then it changes a lot.

Comment: Should these files be automatically suggested by VScode/ Android Studio to be autoimported? I am struggling to get my exported entities in my package to be autoimported for users of my package.

Comment: Is it not possible to export all the files like ``` export ''*.dart'' ```

Comment: @BaimamBoukar No, it is not possible to export more than a single file. This is because, in Dart, a single file defines one library and you can only export single libraries.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no simpler way.

Dart do not offer a directory import.

Answer (score 3):

I create a package to auto export all dart files.
I named it `auto_exporter` you can search it on https://pub.dev/packages

when you are creating a dart package I think it's useful.

Comment: Direct link: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_exporter

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no direct way to automatically include all `.dart` files from a directory.  You should be able to use some form of code generation (e.g. with [source_gen](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/source_gen) or [build](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build)) to generate a `.dart` file at build-time that other files could `import`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [index_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/index_generator) package to generate an `index.dart` file under your `lib` folder. This generated file would contain `export` statements for all your files under the `lib` folder.

Steps (as mentioned in the docs):

1. `<dart|flutter> pub global activate index_generator`
2. Create `index_generator.yaml` file or add in your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
index_generator:
  exclude:
    - '**.g.dart'
  # Define the paths of the folders in which to generate the index files
  indexes:
    - path: lib
```

3. Generate index files with: `<dart|flutter> pub global run index_generator`